# Статичность фона

Tags: css

Подскажите, как сделать фиксированный фон, чтобы при уменьшении окна он не уменьшался, а был статичной и стоял на месте, как и все остальные обьекты.

```
background:url(https://cutewallpaper.org/21/black-gif-background/Black-gif-background-3- 
GIF-Images-Download.gif);
background-position: center 1100px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: black;
object-fit: cover;
```

Нужно чтобы по осям X и Y он всегда располагался по центру, то есть так же как в полноэкранном режиме (1920х1080) и не важно насколько он растянется по X Y или ужмется, главное чтобы был по центру и в аналогичных пропорциях. При `background-size: cover` он становится адаптивным и путешествует по просторам сайта по всем осям.

Comment: `background-size`?

Comment: не помогает, уже пробовал

Comment: А должно помогать.

Comment: немного интерпретирую вопрос, нужно чтобы по осям X и Y он всегда располагался по центру, то-есть также как в полноэкранном режиме (1920х1080) и неважно насколько он растянется по X Y, и ужмется, главное чтобы был по центру и в аналогичных пропорциях. при bg-size:cover он становится адаптивным и путешествует по просторам сайта по всем осям, думаю, так будет мой вопрос яснее

Comment: center center аналогично не помогают

Comment: Потому что contain, а не cover.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/FrqDA.gif) center / contain black;
}
```